# Magento - Saving products is very slow

Tags: magento

When I save a product in the Magento admin it is extremely slow.  It can take around a minute for the product to save.

I found some information in Google that suggested this would be related to the indexing.  I changed the indexing mode so it only updates manually but the problem persists.

For some reason if I select the product and use the 'Update Attributes' option it saves in a few seconds but updating an individual product is painfully slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about your products/categories/attributes/attributes-sets size ?

Comment: do you use a slow_backend cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products saved fine until recently and I am on a semi dedicated server so this wasn't the problem.

However, I have now found the cause of the problem. It was an extension from channelunity.com. I have disabled that and saving products is back to taking a few seconds :)

I have contacted the extensions developer so hopefully they provide a fix.

Comment: I have the same problem, what was the extention and how did you disabled it?

Answer (score 0):

Inadequate system resources and need for MySQL optimization. Find a hosting provider that provides servers tuned for running Magento. 1 minute sounds about right for a shared server that's being choked off by settings that ensure that resources are being shared out equally among all the users on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Magento to upload products use of data import/export is recommended.

Magento Backend is slow  and you need a more powerful resource/server to process things faster.
Also as stated in above post you need to set indexing mode to manual which you have already done.

Also more number of attributes means higher sql query load so check for attributes sets etc.